# Monkey patching inside module to limit its scope

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

Why does this throw an error, when the class and statement is encapsulated in the module??

```
module Xchange

  class Float

    def in currency
      self.to_s << " " << suffix(currency)
    end

    private

    def suffix currency
      case currency
      when :euro
        "euros"
      when :dollar
        "dollars"
      when :rupee
        "rupees"
      end
    end

  end

  puts 2.3.in(:euro)
end
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opps, my mistake! It took me a while to figure out! Just tried to look inside the Float class using Pry and to my surprise found that there are no other Float methods in it. So, I am assuming the Float I was trying to re-define was not the globally available Float. It a new class by the name `Xchange::Float` with a single instance method `in`!

So, in short I believe such a patch will be global and to all files that `requires` it. Hence the point of `refine` in the new version.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a current release of Ruby I would suggest you to go away from monkeypatching and start using Refinements (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) instead. This way you can introduce "monkeypatches" for certain modules much more convenient and in a Ruby native way.

Comment: Well, won't that limit the gem to the current version of Ruby? Somehow feel that it is limiting; though haven't seen any real data to decide.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have declared a new class `Xchange::Float` instead of opening existing `Float` class.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to limit the scope of the changes to Float to be inside Xchange module alone.

Comment: You can't do that - This would mean that you want certain objects to behave differently in different context.